# Green text in editor after using \lstinline{}

Tags: texstudio

Using `\lstinline{}` causes the text behind to change colour from black to green/blue-ish.

[image]

What is the problem, and how do I remove the colour change?

Removing the underscore doesn't seem to be the problem.

I am using TeXstudio as editor

Comment: Did you try with `\lstinline!ISR_AddAngle!`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ivan pointed out, using a different delimitator than `{ }` (like `! !`) solves the issue.

If you want to avoid that green/blue-ish highlighting in general -- as you pointed out in your own answer -- you can change the color for highlighting `verbatim`-elements under `Configure TeXstudio...`>`Syntax Highlighting`>`verbatim`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As Ivan suggested did the use of `\lstinline!...!` instead of `\lstinline{...}` work!

However, does the text between the two `!` still become green/blue-ish, but not a huge problem.